# Create a model association where the model is not a active record model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, associations

I have a model called Client. 
This extends not from ActiveRecord::Base but from my own wrapper class. 
These objects are not stored in my own database.

I have some other models called Answer and Device for example. These are stored in my database with a client_id.

Now, what I want to do is that is can call Answer.client and Client.answers for example. The normal way would be with ActiveRecord associations but that doesn't work is this case.

I can define my own .answers and .client method but in my opinion that's not the way to go with Rails.

Thanks in advance for replying!

Comment: Are you connecting to the other database directly to get the clients?

Comment: What do you mean by directly? @Vimsha

Comment: Are you using a web service to get the clients or you execute queries directly on the other database to get the clients?

Comment: Aah, I'm using a webservice to get the clients. I have it working right now for the moment. I wrote my own methods. But I don't like it to be honest.